# Rabbitmq-server status intermittent failures

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq

Rabbitmq-server package from ubuntu precise: 2.7.1-0ubuntu4

`sudo service rabbitmq-server status` and `sudo rabbitmqctl status` are flip-flopping between running and not running:

```
ubuntu@juju-cstack-machine-2:~$ sudo service rabbitmq-server status
Status of node 'rabbit@juju-cstack-machine-2' ...
[{pid,12657},
 {running_applications,[{rabbit,"RabbitMQ","2.7.1"},
                        {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.2.7"},
                        {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","2.1.10"},
                        {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.5"},
                        {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","1.17.5"},
                        {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.14.5"}]},
 {os,{unix,linux}},
 {erlang_version,"Erlang R14B04 (erts-5.8.5) [source] [64-bit] [rq:1] [async-threads:30] [kernel-poll:true]\n"},
 {memory,[{total,24201136},
          {processes,9867720},
          {processes_used,9863352},
          {system,14333416},
          {atom,1125241},
          {atom_used,1121718},
          {binary,66832},
          {code,11134393},
          {ets,720104}]},
 {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.3999999992241869},
 {vm_memory_limit,206235238}]
...done.
ubuntu@juju-cstack-machine-2:~$ sudo service rabbitmq-server status
Status of node 'rabbit@juju-cstack-machine-2' ...
Error: unable to connect to node 'rabbit@juju-cstack-machine-2': nodedown
diagnostics:
- unable to connect to epmd on juju-cstack-machine-2: address
- current node: 'rabbitmqctl13266@juju-cstack-machine-2'
- current node home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- current node cookie hash: KPS29QESrctoFRh8pBlvwg==
```

I've disabled all the services connecting to it (just one).  I can't figure out what I should do to troubleshoot further?  Any ideas?  The log files are decidedly **unhelpful**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be some kind of issue with the network and host routing.  verifying the hostname and that it was resolvable via the hosts file fixed the problem.